How to deal with duplicate deletion of pointers in C++
Recently I got stuck in a scenario where I was using both raw and smart pointers simultaneously in a project.
I have 2 classes. Canvas which composes another class CanvasItem. It stores CanvasItem pointers in a vector of std::unique_ptr m_canvasItems.
The class has method
void Canvas::Add(CanvasItem* item) {
   m_canvasItems.push_back(std::unique_ptr<CanvasItem>(item)); //Moves ownership of CanvasItem pointer to Canvas class
}

Now in my main.cpp file I have raw pointers of CanvasItems. Which are created and deleted in a render function. Inside render method, CanvasItem pointers are created and then add to m_canvasItems vector in Canvas.
Now when I run memory tests, it throws error that there is a duplicate deletion of a resource. Which is understandable  since the pointer has already been deleted by Canvas class.
Can anyone please suggest me a work around so I somehow revoke the ownership of these pointers in Canvas class, so the cleanup is done by main class instead. I found this link but I cannot figure out if this is what I'm looking for.
Link
Note: I cannot change any logic in main.cpp, so it has to remain intact.
I am responsible for Canvas and CanvasItem class.

if you don't own a pointer you shouldn't be creating a smart pointer from it. You can workaround with a shared_ptr and a no-op deleter but its a bit of a bodge

dont mix raw owning pointers and smart pointers. Your void Canvas::Add is the best example why doing so leads to problems. The raw pointer passed to the function must be an owning pointer before you pass it, and it is no longer an owning pointer after the call, but it is the exact same pointer. Raw pointers have no ownership semantics. THe only ownership they can be used for without problems is : not an owner

perhaps it should be void Canvas::Add(std::unique_ptr<CanvasItem> item)

If you are not meant to assume ownership of the pointers passed to the function then don't assume ownership. If you are not responsible for the lifetime of that object then don't delete it.

If you really want to "move ownership" of the objects, you must do it fully. Once you have "moved" the ownership, you should simply forget about the original pointer, and never use it again.

@AlanBirtles tried with the shared_ptr as well. Still gives me the same error. Perhaps this SHARED OWNERSHIP nature of shared_ptr is only valid with other shared pointers, not with raw pointers.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai changing function definition is not the right approach, as I'd have to cast the raw pointer before passing it to Add(....) in the main.cpp
And changing the main.cpp is not an option as, testing library tests it with the original main.cpp

@Someprogrammerdude yes, I get your point. I'm rolling back to raw pointers for this project.

The entire reason std::unique_ptr exists is to indicate that THIS is the owner of the pointer, and nobody else. The object lives for as long as THAT pointer lives, and absolutely nobody is meant to delete that object. So, don't delete it and you'll be fine. If, on the other hand, you want multiple owners because they want to hold on to the object for a while longer, use std::shared_ptr -- this means the object lives for as long as ANYONE still has a shared_ptr for it.

did you create a custom deleter for your shared_ptr? If you didn't it wont be any different to unique_ptr

"as I'd have to cast the raw pointer before passing it to Add(....) in" no, you misunderstand. As someone said before, you need to go the full way. Dont use a raw owning pointer to begin with. You should never need to pass a raw pointer to Add when Add takes ownership, because raw pointers dont own.

I am convinced this quesiton is going nowhere, unless you create a small example code. Read about [mcve]. Only then we will be able to show you a way out of your issues. Where is the raw owning pointer coming from? Why did you use new somewhere in your code? Thats the root cause of your problems

@463035818_is_not_an_ai the raw pointer is created in the main.cpp which I don't have access to modify. I only have Canvas class. I make the changes in Canvas, upload to the testing tool which runs the tests. So unfortunately the only reproductive example I have is this Add(....) function.
Which is why I explained in the question about where the pointer is coming from.

@ChristianStieber thank you for your brief explanation. I'm going to experiment with it

@AlanBirtles no I did not. Maybe that's why I could not see the difference in behaviour of unique_ptr and smart_ptr.
Thanks for pointing this out. I'll give it a shot.
Appreciate your help

you already described the code, but a description of code in english is not sufficient to know what is actually going on. Details matter. Thats why we ask for a [mcve]

note that whilst you can use a custom deleter to make a non-owning shared_ptr it's rarely a good idea, if you don't own a pointer just don't use a smart pointer, store the raw pointer instead

"Now in my main.cpp file I have raw pointers of CanvasItems. Which are created and deleted in a render function." Canvas doesn't own the CanvasItems, so it shouldn't be deleting them.

whole point of using smart pointers is leak-free code, where objects are created and deleted along respective smart pointers. If there is any sequence point between initialization of smart pointer and obtaining a raw pointer to an object, the existence of smart pointer does't really help anything. Smart pointer is supposed to own the object, i.e. being responsible for creation and deletion, that's why you should use make_unique or make_shared

"How to deal with duplicate deletion of pointers in C++" - 1) don't do it. 2) if you must, set them to nullptr after the first deletion so the second is harmless. But really; read up on ownership and lifetime and just don't get into that situation and avoid raw pointers when possible.

Thanks everyone.
I have resolved the issue. The code owner has opened the access to main class and now I have smart pointers in both main and Canvas classes.
It is working as expected now.
Appreciate your help

As pointed out in a comment, the key point here is

Which are created and deleted in a render function.

You seem to misunderstand what owership is about. Owning some resource means to be responsible to clean it up when it is no longer needed. If a render function deletes the CanvasItems then nobody else shall delete them. The renderer owns them, nobody else shall own them.
Raw owning pointers are difficult and should be avoided. Non owning raw pointers are ok. If the actual resource is managed by a shared_ptr you should prefer weak_ptr as observer.
void Canvas::Add(CanvasItem* item) {
   m_canvasItems.push_back(item); // Do not moves ownership !
}

The canvas merely stores a raw pointer to access the CanvasItem. You have to make sure that the CanvasItem is still alive while the Canvas is accessing it.
